# How to detect physical mute/unmute mic on/off button from external headphone?

Tags: webrtc

I am working on WebRTC project. Now the issue is I am not able to detect whether the user stops the mic by pressing the physical button on the headphone. I tried to find a way to listen to the event but was not able to get any. Can you please suggest whether the same is possible through JavaScript or not to detect the volume/mic on/off event?

Answer (score 0):

The MediaStreamTracks `onmute` event should get called in that case.
If it is not called please file a bug against the respective browser. See also [this recent discussion on the W3C spec](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-extensions/issues/39)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried but it does not trigger on "onmute". But, I tested the with google meets and zoom application and they are able to stop the audio when the user off the mic through the physical button. So, it seems there is some other event that is triggering the same.

Comment: they might be detecting silence. See e.g. the silence detection here: https://github.com/webrtc/testrtc/blob/ce0456d0e5e20f5c7b2c98cac1479f02611b1268/src/js/mictest.js#L93

Comment: I have checked the and tried to implement the same buts it's not working.

Comment: After multiple R&D, it confirms that we don't have to do any specific handling to stop audio when the user mutes audio from the physical mute button. When I tested in the application it works in one case but it failed in another case which I am still working to identify the case. Otherwise, we don't need to make any handling for the same. I will share my finding accordingly.